# Pandas - Processing DF with multiple identifier into a combined column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have below DF that i wanted to process to be like the sample below. Im having a hard time due to the identifier is sharing the column where what site they are located. the column location is also not fix as there are certain times where the "Land" has 30days whereas the "Water" only has 5 days

Thank you for helping me

Sample DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Unnamed: 0': ['Site',"A", "B","C"],
               'Unnamed: 1': ['Identifier 1',"Land", "Land","Land"],
               'Unnamed: 2': ['Day 1',1, 2,3],
               'Unnamed: 3': ['Day 2',4, 5,6],
               'Unnamed: 4': ['Day 3',7, 8,9],
               'Unnamed: 5': ['Day 4',10, 11,12],
               'Unnamed: 6': ['Identifier 2',"Water", "Water","Water"],
               'Unnamed: 7': ['Day 1',13, 14,15],
               'Unnamed: 8': ['Day 2',16, 17,18],
               'Unnamed: 9': ['Day 3',19, 20,21],
               'Unnamed: 10': ['Day 4',22, 23,24],
               })
```

Output file:

```html
Site    Identifier 1    Day 1   Day 2   Day 3   Day 4
A   Land    1   4   7   10
B   Land    2   5   8   11
C   Land    3   6   9   12
A   Water   13  16  19  22
B   Water   14  17  20  23
C   Water   15  18  21  24
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you wanted ? I would first split into 2 dataframes with each containing different identifier and at the end union them back tgt.  here's the code and hope it helps.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Unnamed: 0': ['Site',"A", "B","C"],
           'Unnamed: 1': ['Identifier 1',"Land", "Land","Land"],
           'Unnamed: 2': ['Day 1',1, 2,3],
           'Unnamed: 3': ['Day 2',4, 5,6],
           'Unnamed: 4': ['Day 3',7, 8,9],
           'Unnamed: 5': ['Day 4',10, 11,12],
           'Unnamed: 6': ['Identifier 2',"Water", "Water","Water"],
           'Unnamed: 7': ['Day 1',13, 14,15],
           'Unnamed: 8': ['Day 2',16, 17,18],
           'Unnamed: 9': ['Day 3',19, 20,21],
           'Unnamed: 10': ['Day 4',22, 23,24],
           })
## Restriving Column Name
header = [item for item in df.iloc[0]]

## Filter Out the first row 
df = df.iloc[1:]


# Getting first 6 columns as df_land and rename column by header
df_land = df.iloc[:, 0:6]
df_land.columns = header[:6]

# Getting the first column and the last 5 columns as df_water and rename column by header
df_water = df.iloc[:,[0,6,7,8,9,10]]
df_water.columns = header[:6]

# Union two tables
df_final = pd.concat( [df_land,df_water] , axis = 0 )
```

---

Edit - for Dynamic N Column

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Unnamed: 0': ['Site',"A", "B","C"],
           'Unnamed: 1': ['Identifier 1',"Land", "Land","Land"],
           'Unnamed: 2': ['Day 1',1, 2,3],
           'Unnamed: 3': ['Day 2',4, 5,6],
           'Unnamed: 4': ['Day 3',7, 8,9],
           'Unnamed: 5': ['Day 4',10, 11,12],
           'Unnamed: 11': ['Day 5',10, 11,12],
           'Unnamed: 12': ['Day 6',10, 11,12],
           'Unnamed: 6': ['Identifier 2',"Water", "Water","Water"],
           'Unnamed: 7': ['Day 1',13, 14,15],
           'Unnamed: 8': ['Day 2',16, 17,18],
           'Unnamed: 9': ['Day 3',19, 20,21],
           'Unnamed: 10': ['Day 4',22, 23,24],
#            'Unnamed: 13': ['Day 5',22, 23,24],
           })
## Restriving Column Name
header = [item for item in df.iloc[0]]

## Filter Out the first row 
df = df.iloc[1:]

n_col = len(header)
n_of_column_exclude_from_land = 5

# Getting first 6 columns as df_land and rename column by header
df_land = df.iloc[:, 0:n_col-n_of_column_exclude_from_land]
df_land.columns = header[:n_col-n_of_column_exclude_from_land]

# Getting the first column and the last 5 columns as df_water and rename column by header
water_col_index = [n for n in range(n_col-n_of_column_exclude_from_land,n_col)]
water_col_index.append(0)
water_col_index.sort()


df_water = df.iloc[:,water_col_index]
df_water.columns = header[:n_of_column_exclude_from_land+1]

# Union two tables
df_final = pd.concat( [df_land,df_water] , axis = 0 )
```

Comment: thank you @humphrey, i wonder how can i dynamically make the iloc instead of fixed one, because the data is not fix on column 6.

Comment: you may change n_of_column_exclude_from_land depending how many days you have for water identifier.  for example, if water identifier have only 4 days than put 5 (4 days + 1 for the water identifier column = 5) if have 5 days then put 6.

for example, if I uncomment Unnamed: 13, then I will change N_of_column_exclude.... = 6 and it should work.